# Android-Creating a runtime Edittext when a Button is Clicked

Tags: android

I am new to android.I just what to create a Edittext at a run time when a button is clicked.for example in contact when the image + is clicked it will add a button and a edittext in the layout.can anyone help me with some sample codes.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this u need to create a layout which is set on click of button.
Chk out dis  :[button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)

Comment: If you don't mind explaining a little more... I'm also interested in the answer. Are you refering to layoutInflater?

Comment: No u can create the layout using xml file also